# Adding a nested List in R

Tags: r

I am unable to add a nested list as a component to a list using c(). Pls. consider the example:

```
list1 <- list(1,2)
list3 <- c(list1, "list2"=list("a",4))
list3[4]
```

This gives:

```
$`list22
[1] 4`
```

But there is no 4th component. As per the instruction manual I am following, we can add new component to a list by

```
new_list <- c(old_list, new_component)
```

I have added the new component (`list2`) and it is the 3rd component. `append()` also gives the same result.

Comment: `list1 <- list(1,2);list1[["list2"]] <-list("a",4);list1` ???

Comment: `c(list1,"list2"=list(c("a",4)))`.

Comment: He wants a list with two elements: the first being the list (1,2), the second being the list ('a', 4). The expected result of len(list3) should be 2, and therefore he is suprised he can access the 4th element of list3. However I would be surprised if this question had not be covered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the comment by @Hobo Sheep is correct (a list of length 2):

```
list1 <- list(1,2)

list3 <- list(
    list1,
    list(
        list2 = list(
            "a", 
            3
        )
    )
)

length(list3)
```

If you want to use `append`

```
list3 <- append(list1, list(list2 = list("a", 3)))
str(list3)
```

A `list` in R ~= JSON, so if you are more familiar with the latter:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(list3, auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
```

Comment: The above works with 'c' as well as 'append'. list3 <- c(list1, list(list2 = list("a", 3)))